# Creating a new material without adding a new material slot

Tags: materials

I'm trying to figure out how to create a new material at an existing material slot on an object. If you add a *new* material slot to an object, the interface displays a "New" button to let you create a new material for it:
[image: screenshot of newly added material slot]

But if you've previously added a material slot and assigned faces to it, and later want to create a new material for use with the slot, there's no obvious way to do this directly. The materials drop-down for the slot has no option to create a new material:
[image: screenshot of materials dropdown for an existing material slot]

and I haven't found any quick way in other interfaces, like the Shading tab, to request creating a new material for an existing slot.

So: is there any quick way to tell Blender to create a new material without adding a new slot to an object? Yes, you can add a temporary slot, click "New" to create a material, delete the slot, and assign the new material to the existing slot where you wanted it to be, but it feels like there should be a less silly way to do it.

Comment: Remove the material from the slot and the *New* button shows up, or press the *Copy* button to the rigth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restate Duarte's reply with a screenshot, click the "x" button next to the name of the material currently assigned to the slot to un-assign the material. After this, the "New" button to create a new material will appear.

[image: screenshot highlighting the x button]